# Opening a local Android File with spaces

Tags: android

I am trying to open a local file in Android (4.0) using intents. The following is the code to do the action. This works fine as long as the file has no special spaces (For example: if the file is /data/data/com.xxxx.yyyy/files/Downloads/Documents/ProductFeature.pptx, the it opens fine, but if the file name is  /data/data/com.xxxx.yyyy/files/Downloads/Documents/Product Feature.pptx (note the space in name), then it fails. The Uri.fromFile encodes the space correctly, but the other apps cant seem to interpret them and seem fail opening.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    Uri uri =  Uri.fromFile(new File( selectedEntry.get(Defs.PATH_KEY)));
    System.out.println("openFileWith: File to open: " + uri);

    intent.setDataAndType(uri,type);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open With ..."));
```

I also tried to use "file://" + unencoded path without much help.

So how do you handle this condition? Any help is appreciated

Comment: try "\ " instead of " " . I am not sure though, just give it a try

Comment: Try replacing the space with either a + sign or %20 or try adding double quotes around the name.

Comment: @pvn I tried that and it doesn't seem to help. Thanks for the suggestion. I didnt even try that before.

Comment: @SylvainL The %20 is generated when Uri.fromFile (as it encoded) and that doesnt work, I will try the "+" sign and report
Thanks!

Comment: If you try with the double quotes, try with both the following versions: "/data/data/com.xxxx.yyyy/files/Downloads/Documents/ProductFeature.pptx" or  /data/data/com.xxxx.yyyy/files/Downloads/Documents/"ProductFeature.pptx"

Comment: @SylvainL Tried both options of double quotes and same problem (I tried it with Uri.parse("file://" + name), Uri.fromFile(new File(name)) .

Comment: What kind of file/application is that?

Comment: @SylvainL This app downloads a file from server and then allows that file to opened with other installed apps. In this case I seems to launch polarisviewer app to open that pptx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the spaces with `"\ "`. Note that if you are using `String.replace()` then you need to escape the slash as well (`"\\ "`).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem for me turned out to be I was storing files in application directory of internal storage and the access to the files had to be given explicitly. I was giving permissions using chmod 755 command. But the files with spaces were not getting the permissions set correctly which prevented those files being opened.

I have since moved to use external (Activity.getExternalFilesDir()) and that folder allows access permission to every other application and that solved the issue for me.