# Android Read Text File from URI

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent, text

I've got a `Uri` pointing to a text file from an `intent` and I'm trying to read the file to parse the string inside it. This is what I've tried but it's failing with `FileNotFoundException`. The `toString()` method appears to lose a `/`

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.google.android.apps.bigtop/attachments/downloads/528c4088144d1515d933ca406b7bc273/attachments/d_0_0_b562310a_52b6ec1c_c4d5f0d3_73f7489a_711e4cf2/untitled%20text.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
String text = data.toString();
if(data != null) {

    try {
       File f = new File(text);
       FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f); // Fails on this line
       int size = is.available();
       byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
       is.read(buffer);
       is.close();
       text = new String(buffer);
       Log.d("attachment: ", text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The value of data is:

> content://com.google.android.apps.bigtop/attachments/downloads/528c4088144d1515d933ca406b7bc273/attachments/d_0_0_b562310a_52b6ec1c_c4d5f0d3_73f7489a_711e4cf2/untitled%20text.txt

and the value of data.getPath() is

> /attachments/downloads/528c4088144d1515d933ca406b7bc273/attachments/d_0_0_b562310a_52b6ec1c_c4d5f0d3_73f7489a_711e4cf2/untitled text.txt

I'm now trying to get the file directly from the Uri rather than the path:

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
String text = data.toString();
//...
File f = new File(text);
```

But f appears to lose one of the slashes from content://

f:

> content:/com.google.android.apps.bigtop/attachments/downloads/528c4088144d1515d933ca406b7bc273/attachments/d_0_0_b562310a_52b6ec1c_c4d5f0d3_73f7489a_711e4cf2/untitled%20text.txt

Comment: Did you try to check this, I see that you have white space in your filename http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301674/save-file-in-android-with-spaces-in-file-name.

Comment: @aleksamarkoni i've reencoded the url with %20 instead of a " " but still FileNotFoundException

Comment: Can you please check if SD card is available at the moment of trying. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage

Comment: and also please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488794/opening-a-local-android-file-with-spaces

Comment: @aleksamarkoni the external storage is available and replacing " " with "\\ " didn't help

Comment: use `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` to get the content. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream%28android.net.Uri%29

Answer (score 13):

```
Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);


            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line; (line = r.readLine()) != null; ) {
                total.append(line).append('\n');
            }

            String content = total.toString();



        }catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it is working perfectly

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If i may ask what is this FOR? I've never seen this syntax

Comment: @E.Akio It is Java :)

Comment: Great! Not what i expected but i'll search for it then :)

Answer (score -2):

**Read Text** from **File**:

```
private String readText() {
    File f = new File(Your_File_Path);
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int i;
    try {
        i = inputStream.read();
        while (i != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = inputStream.read();
        }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
```

This function will **return** **String**, use it as your requirement.

Use as below:

```
Log.i("Text from File", readText());
```

**Done**

Comment: This obviously is _not_ the answer. The input stream should originate from Uri, not from File/Path. Especially in terms of the emphasis upon content Uri not file Uri by Google.